# What's the difference between "außerdem" and "ferner"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I thought both meant "moreover". But sometimes I see the first, sometimes the second term being used, in almost identical contexts.

What is the difference?

Comment: Which examples did you find (together with context, please)? Which dictionary did you consult and what explanation did it offer? Have you been able to use & understand a german-german dictionary like dwds.de?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the "moreover" context both words are synonyms, just like *überdies*. A difference is that *außerdem* only knows this context, but *ferner* can occur in other contexts, too, having a different meaning, i.e. "nichts liegt mir ferner."

Comment: Umm... I think those two contexts for "ferner" are for two different words? Or would you say that "ferner liefen" as stated above has the "ferner" meant as if it was the comperative of "fern"?

Comment: No. Yes. "Ferner" is always the comparative of "fern" and always describes either physical or virtual distance: "In ferner Zukunft" is the same usage as "Gewinner waren... Ferner wurden gekührt:..." - it describes something that is apart from the current position/focus.

Comment: ("gekürt", of course)

Answer (score 2):

Die Begriffe sind, soweit ich sehe, synonym.

*Ferner* ist nicht mehr so geläufig, aber es gibt den stehenden Ausdruck "der Rest lief unter *ferner liefen*" aus dem Pferdesport, bei dem semantisch *außerdem liefen* auch nicht falsch wäre, aber *ferner liefen* hat sich eingebürgert.

Comment: Die Betrachtung zu "außerdem liefen" verwirrt hier eher den Fragesteller, wette ich.

Comment: Nun, mit einer Reputation von 293 sollte er dann einen Kommentar abgeben können.